# Составление рейтинговых списков

Tags: mysql

Необходимо создать БД приемной комиссии. В дальнейшем на основание рейтинговых списков необходимо будет составлять списки к зачислению.

Как лучше представить в БД рейтинговые списки? Для каждого направления обучения создать отдельную таблицу с необходимыми сведениями (инфо об абитуриенте, баллы по предметам и др.)?!

Потом по этим рейтинговым спискам будет проходить алгоритм поиска абитуриентов.

Черновые таблицы БД пока выглядят так:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 4):

Таблица направлений

```
id | title | дополнительные колонки (описание и т.п.)
```

Таблица предметов

```
id | title | дополнительные колонки (описание и т.п.)
```

Таблица отношений предметов к направлениям - обеспечит связь многие-ко-многим между направлениями и предметами. Для нахождения всех предметов по направлений просто выбираем `SELECT * FROM relations WHERE specialization_id = ID направления` (плюс джойн).

```
specialization_id | discipline_id
```

Таблица абитуриентов

```
id | last_name | first_name | middle_name | birthdate | ...
```

И, наконец, таблица баллов абитуриентов

```
enrollee_id | discipline_id | mark
```

Связь опять многие-ко-многим

Comment: А если сформировать таблицу с рейтинговыми списками так:
выбрать из таблицы сведений абитуриента людей с необходимым кодом специальности и сформировать список. Таким образом будут созданы необходимые списки на основании выборки сведений из общих таблиц. 
Черновые таблицы БД пока выглядят так.
http://i65.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0713/6a/fcfb281ec0e4e4cf3c097f8d9f30286a.png