# Рейтинговые списки

Tags: mysql

Уточню свой предыдущий вопрос.

Необходимо создать БД приемной комиссии. В дальнейшем на основание рейтинговых списков необходимо будет составлять списки к зачислению. Как лучше представить в БД рейтинговые списки? Потом по этим рейтинговым спискам будет проходить алгоритм поиска абитуриентов.

Абитуриент ставит приоритет 1, 2 и 3. Соответственно, самое приоритетное направление под номером 1. Из рейтингового списка зачисляются студенты с приоритетом 1, если они проходят по конкурсу.

Допустим, есть 10 бюджетных мест на направление Х. Из списка для направления Х берутся первые 10 человек. Из них сразу можно взять людей с приоритетом 1. Если приоритет 2, то необходимо посмотреть ситуацию в более приоритетном направление (это уже новый список). В нем тоже самое - берутся первые У людей, чье число соответствует числу бюджетных мест, и просматривается как ситуация обстоит там. Если проходит в приоритете - зачисляется абитуриент там, освобождая при этом место в менее приоритетном направление. Если нет - при наличие мест зачисляется на второй приоритет.

**Вариант 1:** Для каждого направления обучения создать отдельную таблицу с необходимыми сведениями (инфо об абитуриенте, баллы по предметам и др.).

Плюсы - легко можно составить запрос и перейти к нужной таблицы направления.

Минусы - много однотипных таблиц.

**Вариант 2:** Создать одну большую таблицу со всеми абитуриентами ВУЗа. Выбрать из этой таблицы сведения абитуриента с необходимым кодом направления и сформировать список для данного направления. Таким образом будут созданы необходимые списки на основании выборки сведений из общей таблицы.

Минусы - сложности с запросами

Comment: > Плюсы - легко можно составить запрос и перейти к нужной таблицы направления.

Уже на пятидесяти абитуриентах будет "легко"

Comment: а mysql обязательное условие ?

Comment: Работаю с MySQL в основном. Другие варианты не рассматривал.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте к [таблицам, предложенным Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/335422/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-mysql), еще одну, которая свяжет специализации и абитуриентов:

```
id | abiturient_id | specialization_id | priority
```